# Bifunctors in Haskell vs in category theory

Tags: haskell, category-theory, bifunctor

In Haskell, the class `Bifunctor`is defined as follow :

```hs
class Bifunctor p where
  bimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
```

In category theory, a bifunctor is, according to [ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bifunctor), "simply a functor whose domain is a product category :  for C1, C2 and D categories, a functor F:C1×C2⟶D is called a bifunctor  from C1 and C2 to D."

Now if I had to implement the categorical definition, I would write the following :

```hs
class MyBifunctor p where
  myBimap :: ((a,c) -> (b,d)) -> p a c -> p b d
```

In particular, `myBimap` looks a lot like `fmap`, which is what I suppose we want since, again, a bifunctor *is* a functor.

Now to push this even further, since `base 4.18.0`, a quantified constraint has been added :

```hs
class (forall a. Functor (p a)) => Bifunctor p where
    bimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
```

This quantified constraint tells us that a bifunctor is a functor *in its second argument*, which definitely doesn't match with the categorical definition.

I understand that from the class `Bifunctor`, one can get *some* bifunctors, the ones where the types of the first and second arguments do not interact, but not *all* of them. Actually, I'd even say that the class `Bifunctor` implements a *product* of two functors, and not a bifunctor at all.

So my question is the following : Did I misunderstood something ? Or are bifunctors in Haskell not really bifunctors ? Does the class `MyBifunctor` makes sense ?

Comment: You're basically correct, it's just that `MyBifunctor` is just a restriction on `Functor` to functions on pairs, which is a better match for the definition in category theory but doesn't seem immediately useful to me.

Comment: I don't like the `(a,c) -> (b,d)` part -- that's not a morphism in the product category, since that would be (roughly) `(a->b, c->d)` instead. The issue here is that Haskell notation is misleading: `(a,b)` in Haskell is the product object `a` times `b`, and not the pair of objects (the object in the product category).

Comment: @chi That's a very good point, thank you. As a matter of fact if we need a morphism of the product category, `(a->b, c->d)`, then with curryfication we get `bimap`.

But I'm not sure that's what we want : for a functor F : C ⟶D,  its `fmap` takes an arrow from the category C right ? If that's so the type `(a,c) -> (b,d)` would be correct, but I'm not sure

Comment: I think that `Bifunctor` only handles functors of the form `p :: Hask * Hask -> Hask` (to be curried), where "Hask" is the fictional category where Haskell types live in. After all, the `Functor` class also only handles Hask->Hask functors. Perhaps one could try being more general using something like `Control.Category.Category` and define (bi)functors there. Maybe it's already done in some package on Hackage (?)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me, thanks a lot. I'll go have a look

Comment: By "a functor whose domain is a product category" yes, we do want a morphism of the product category.

Comment: Yes I see that now, that solves my question. `MyBifunctor` is actually just a weird kind of partial endofunctor that only maps objects which are product objects (and we don't know what it does to non product objects, which is bad, and which is also why it's not a functor at all)

Comment: @chi https://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories-1.0.7/docs/Control-Categorical-Bifunctor.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `MyBifunctor` is incorrect. Morphisms in the product category are not morphisms between pairs of objects (what would that even mean, in the generalized categorical setting?), but rather pairs of morphisms between objects. Compare:

```
((a,c) -> (b,d)) -> p a c -> p b d -- incorrect
(a -> b, c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d -- correct
```

The correct version is morally isomorphic to the version in the base library:

```
(a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d -- base, also correct
```

> This quantified constraint tells us that a bifunctor is a functor in its second argument, which definitely doesn't match with the categorical definition.

It actually does match the categorical definition. Given a bifunctor `B` and an object `c` of the first source category `C`, the induced operation `F = B(c, -)` can be defined, which maps objects `d` to `B(c, d)` and arrows `f : d1 -> d2` to `B(id_c, f)`. It's pretty easy to verify that `F` satisfies the functor laws:

```
F(id_d) = B(id_c, id_d) = id_B(c,d) = id_F(d)
F(f) . F(g) = B(id_c, f) . B(id_c, g) = B(id_c . id_c, f . g) = B(id_c, f . g) = F(f . g)
```

In each case, the second equality is justified by the bifunctor laws (or the functor laws with the product category as the source category, if you prefer). An almost identical argument shows that `B(-,d)` is also a functor, but there's no easy way to express that constraint in Haskell.

Comment: I would add that a bifunctor is also functorial in the first argument-- if you keep the second one fixed. Interestingly, a mapping CxC->C that is functorial in each argument separately is not necessarily a bifunctor, because the two applications of functoriality may not commute in general. Categories with such a weird binary operator are called premonoidal.

Comment: @BartoszMilewski Parametricity guarantees the commutativity law of bifunctors. https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2018/03/30/parametricity-for-bifunctor/

Comment: Parametricity is a property of a language that uses parametirc polymorphism (specifically, system F). So, indeed, within system F, you can't define a bifunctor without commutativity. But mathematically this is possible. There is an [nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/funny+tensor+product) about it with an example .

Answer (score 0):

Haskell Bifunctors are **curried** unlike category theory, that means that rather than being functors from a product category ([`FunctorOf (Prod (->) (->)) (->)`](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/eoo16m/base_category_polymorphic_functor_and_functorof/)) they are functors into a functor category (`FunctorOf (->) (Nat (->) (->))`).

This mirrors how functions from tuples (`(a, b) -> c`) are curried into functions into functions (`a -> (b -> c)`).

```hs
                   Prod (->) (->)  (->)
                   |               |
                   vvvvvvvvvvvv    vvvv
UncurriedEither :: (Type, Type) -> Type
(Curried)Either :: Type -> Type -> Type
                   ^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                   |       |
                   (->)    Nat (->) (->)
```

A product category `Prod (->) (->) '(a, b) '(a', b')` is *not* the same as `((a, b) -> (a', b'))`: it is the same as a tuple of functions `(a -> a', b -> b')`.

```hs
type Prod :: Cat k -> Cat j -> Cat (k, j)
data Prod cat1 cat2 pair pair' where
  Prod :: cat1 a a'
       -> cat2 b b'
       -> Prod cat1 cat2 '(a, b) '(a', b')
```

That means the "uncurried Bifunctor" is

```hs
type  UncurriedBifunctor :: ((Type, Type) -> Type) -> Constraint
class UncurriedBifunctor bi where
  bimap :: (a -> a', b -> b') -> bi '(a, b) -> bi '(a', b')
```

which doesn't fit any standard Haskell datatypes, since they are all curried.